# convert linux file to html

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that generates a file in below format. How do i convert this so that i can send email via postfix.

The format below:-

```
                     CERTNAME                                               CREATION                    EXPIRATION                 EXPIRED/EXPIRING
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt                         Sep 29 00:00:00 2016 GMT     Sep 30 23:59:59 2017 GMT        NO
                        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt                         Jun 22 00:00:00 2016 GMT     Jun 23 23:59:59 2017 GMT        NO
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt                         Feb  5 00:00:00 2015 GMT     Feb  6 23:59:59 2016 GMT        YES
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt                         Dec 23 00:00:00 2015 GMT     Dec 23 23:59:59 2016 GMT        NO
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt                         Mar  7 00:00:00 2016 GMT     Mar  8 23:59:59 2017 GMT        NO
                    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.crt                         Dec 17 00:00:00 2014 GMT     Dec 18 23:59:59 2015 GMT        YES
```

Comment: Why do the files need to be html to send over email?

Comment: Many would consider html e-mail taboo. If you want to e-mail the file, why not use something like heirloom-mailx (e.g. [s-nail](https://www.sdaoden.eu/code.html), then just `mailx -a filename -s "the subject" someone@somedomain.tld`

Comment: The problem is that when i send these files with mailx the output in outlook seems distorted. So i was thinking whether converting it to a html format may display the formatting correctly

Comment: Don't confuse two unrelated issues. First decide, whether you want to have text/plain or text/html in your email. If you prefer text mail, and it doesn't work, then solve this problem - for instance by posting it here, explaining what character transfer encoding and what character set you had used for the email.